# iOS - My TextBox spawns a regular keyboard when clicked, how can I set it to spawn a numeric keyboard?

Tags: ios, textbox, keyboard, numeric

Basically I am new to iOS development. I have several text boxes where I want a user to enter a percentage (not letters) so I will only need a numeric keyboard. When the user has done this I also want them to easily get rid of the keyboard.

In the simplest way possible, just treat me like a drunken 5-year-old here, can someone guide me through the steps needed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an UITextField:

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Comment: But where would I even type this? Just treat me like the silly beginner I am!

Comment: Did you set up Xcode or a toolchain? Do you know how to create a basic app using Apple's developer tools?

Comment: Then type this right after the code with which you create the text field (NB you shouldn't be developing apps yet if such a fundamental thing is a problem. I'd recommend you learn a bit more C, Objective-C and get some more understanding of this algorithmical kind of sense or you'll shoot yourself *and your users* in the foot.)

Comment: It's more I'm just chucking myself in the deep end to give it a go. I wouldn't dream of releasing anything I've made until I have a better understanding.

Comment: I don't understand when you say right after the code with which you create the text field, when am I looking?

Comment: Euh, if you create (alloc-init) your text field programmatically, then after the alloc-init; if you use a XIB, then somewhere when it's created (maybe in viewDidLoad of your VC?)

Comment: If you have defined the text field in a xib, you can set the keyboard type there as well. Note that this is still only half an answer - the question also asks for a way for the user to dismiss the keyboard.